# Binance API 'Unauthorized' Reponse

Tags: c#, api, binance, error-code, binance-api-client

I've made a call of `Client.MakeRequest("/api/v3/account");` to check if I'm authorized to make such a call, but I keep getting an error status 'unauthorized' everytime I make the call.

```
public static void MakeRequest(string endpoint)
    {
      var client = new RestClient("https://api.binance.com");

      long timestamp = GetTimestamp();

      RestRequest request = new RestRequest(endpoint, Method.GET);

      request.AddHeader("X-MBX-APIKEY", API_KEY);

      request.AddQueryParameter("recvWindow", "5000");
      request.AddQueryParameter("timestamp", timestamp.ToString());

      request.AddQueryParameter("signature", CreateSignature(request.Parameters, API_SECRET));

      RestResponse response = (RestResponse)client.Get(request);
      System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(response.Content);

    }

    public static string CreateSignature(List<Parameter> parameters, string secret)
    {
      var signature = "";
      if (parameters.Count > 0)
      {
        foreach (var item in parameters)
        {
          if (item.Name != "X-MBX-APIKEY")
            signature += $"{item.Name}={item.Value}&";
        }
        signature = signature.Substring(0, signature.Length - 1);
      }


      byte[] keyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secret);
      byte[] queryStringBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(signature);
      HMACSHA256 hmacsha256 = new HMACSHA256(keyBytes);

      byte[] bytes = hmacsha256.ComputeHash(queryStringBytes);

      return BitConverter.ToString(bytes).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
    }

    private static long GetTimestamp()
    {
      return new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.UtcNow).ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();
    }
```

I'm sure the signature is correct as I've followed the specifications from: https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#public-api-definitions

Other than that i've been debugging for a while and still can't quite figure out the mistake i'm making.

Comment: Don't you need to convert to a base64? I would try this: [how-to-generate-hmac-signature-in-c-sharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57423084/how-to-generate-hmac-signature-in-c-sharp) It looks like there is a difference between `BitConverter.ToString` and `ToBase64String` - [bitconverter-tostring-vs-convert-tobase64string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337742/bitconverter-tostring-vs-convert-tobase64string)

Comment: Still the same results, I'm receiving the error message ```{"code":-2015,"msg":"Invalid API-key, IP, or permissions for action."}```, I'm certain it cannot be my API-KEY that's incorrect, neither my permissions, so @qTzz may be correct about my IP being the reason behind the 'unauthorization;.

Answer (score 1):

The endpoint is returning an unauthorized error so you're definitely hitting the endpoint. I see in the documentation that the API key can be restricted to specific IP addresses so check if the API key is correct and has no restrictions. If it does, make sure your IP configured to use the API key.

Comment: How would I go about configuring my IP to use the API key?

Comment: Go to your API management and edit restrictions. https://www.binance.com/en/support/faq/360002502072

Comment: It's already setup to accept all calls made from any IP address. It's still giving me the "unauthorised" error message.

Comment: Double check you're using the correct API Key or try creating another one. Not sure what else to try with the given information.

Comment: I've managed to fix the API Issue and I've ended up with another, any chance you know I can fix this as I'm sure the signature is correct: '```"StatusCode: BadRequest, Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8, Content-Length: 63)"```

Comment: Maybe it is the signature parameter you're sending, you should only need recvWindow and timestamp according to the documentation, you're already using the API KEY in the header. What ended up being the issue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241069/discussion-between-qtzz-and-sylas-coker).